# Transforming std::map into ordered std::vector

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

I have a `std::map` that stores a string and a class and i want to make an ordered vector based on the value of a class attribute. However, when i iterate over the vector, nothing prints. My code so far is this and the compiler sees no errors:

```
void Championship::orderTeams(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, class Team> > vect, std::map<std::string, class Team>& map) {
    for (auto const& entry : map)
    {
        if (vect.empty()) { //check if vector is empty and add the first pair
            vect.push_back(std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second));
            continue;
        }

        for (auto pos = vect.begin(); pos != vect.end(); ++pos) {
            if(entry.second.points > pos->second.points){
                vect.insert(pos, std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second));

            }else if (pos==vect.end()){
                //vect.insert(pos, std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second)); //wanted to check if there's a differance between insert and push_back
                vect.push_back(std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class `Team` only contains 3 public `int` values( `points`, `goalsTaken` and `goalsGiven`), constructor and distructor.

The vector of pairs is called `teamOrdered` and i printed using:

```
    for (const auto & team : teamOrdered){
        std::cout<<team.first<<" "<<team.second.points<<" "<<team.second.goalsScored<<" "<<team.second.goalsTaken<<std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: Push everything into the `vector`. The call `std::sort` with a custom comparator for it. In your current code, when you `insert` into the vector, you probably want to break that inner loop. You can remove the `class` from the `pair` and `map` in your function header. You also need to pass in the `vector` by reference, otherwise any changes to it inside the function, will be lost.

Comment: The problem is that you take the `vector` by value into this function. The vector is gone when the function returns. If you're calling it like `orderTeams(output, input)`, that means you copy `output` into the function parameter `vect`, and the function modifies and destroys `vect`, and then at the end nothing has happened to `output`. The signature should probably be `void orderTeams(std::vector<...> &out, std::map<...> const &in)`, or maybe just `std::vector<...> orderTeams(std::map<...> const &in)`. (Adding `const` to the `map` because it seems right.)

Comment: orderTeams takes a copy of the vector, so all its changes will be lost, is this intentional?

Comment: What OMGtechy said. Nothing prints because you pass vector by value to the function: it copies the vector you pass to the function(argument) into a new local vector(parameter), then modifies this new vector inside the function, and then this new vector goes out of scope, it never modifies the vector you pass to the function. You either need to pass the vector by reference or return the sorted vector instead.

Comment: @OP -- If you are coming from languages that use references to objects like Java or similar, C++ doesn't work this way (by default).  C++ has value semantics, where everything will be passed (or copied) by-value unless you specify that a reference be passed.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie he passed map by reference, so he probably just missed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a few issues in your code. Firstly, the reason why you get no output at all, is because the `vector` is passed in by value; therefore, any changes to `vect` inside the function are lost. You want to pass it in by reference instead. You can also pass the map in by `const` reference, since you don't need to change the map.

On top of that, your sort method doesn't actually work. Consider the inner for-loop's condition, `pos != vect.end()`; however, you have an `else if` which is `pos == vect.end()`, which is simply impossible. Further, even after the element is added, you keep attempting to add it to `vect`, with a potentially invalid iterator (inserting into a `vector` may cause iterator invalidity).

Here's a working example of you code:

```
void Championship::orderTeams(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Team>> &vect, const std::map<std::string, Team>& map) {
    for (auto const& entry : map)
    {
        if (vect.empty()) { //check if vector is empty and add the first pair
            vect.push_back(std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second));
            continue;
        }

        bool added = false;
        for (auto pos = vect.begin(); pos != vect.end(); ++pos) {
            if(entry.second.points > pos->second.points){
                vect.insert(pos, std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second));
                added = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!added){
            vect.push_back(std::make_pair(entry.first, entry.second));
        }
    }
}
```

This can also be simplified, using `std::sort` from the `algorithm` header, and instead of taking in a vector, you can return one instead.

```
std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Team>> orderTeams2( const std::map<std::string, Team>& map) {
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, Team>> vect = { map.begin(), map.end() };
    std::sort( vect.begin(), vect.end(), []( auto &left, auto &right ) {
        return left.second.points > right.second.points;
    });
    return vect;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by other people, nothing prints for you because you passed vector by value. Pass it by reference or return the vector.

Also, you can sort using `std::sort` and a predicate. Here's a working solution:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

class Team {
public:
    int points;
    int goalsTaken;
    int goalsGiven;
};

void orderTeams(std::vector<std::pair<std::string, class Team> >& vect, std::map<std::string, class Team>& map) {

        for(auto currentIterator = map.begin(); currentIterator != map.end(); ++currentIterator) {
            vect.emplace_back(currentIterator->first, currentIterator->second);
        }

        std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(),
            [](const std::pair<std::string, class Team>& item1, const std::pair<std::string, class Team>& item2) -> bool { return item1.second.points > item2.second.points; });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::pair<std::string, class Team>> teamOrdered;
    std::map<std::string, class Team> map;
    map.emplace(std::string("4"), Team{ 4, 4, 4 });
    map.emplace(std::string("2"), Team{ 2, 2, 2});
    map.emplace(std::string("1"), Team{ 1, 1, 1 });
    map.emplace(std::string("3"), Team{ 3, 3, 3});
    orderTeams(teamOrdered, map);


    for(const auto& team : teamOrdered) {
        std::cout << team.first << " " << team.second.points << " " << team.second.goalsGiven << " " << team.second.goalsTaken << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `sort` is in reverse order from what OP originally had (large to small)

Comment: Fixed it. Thanks.